# codeigniter after submission if refresh submit again

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is simple I guess but I am new to codeigniter, so please help. I have a form page that takes data and when submitted stores that data in database. I then tried two ways to redirect back to main page:

```
first: $this->load->view('home');

second: redirect('/login/form/', 'refresh');
```

They successfully redirect or load the home page, but url is still /property/new_property which is the view for data input. also when I click refresh on the home page with url as stated above, data is resubmitted so multiple records in database. How can I redirect to home and make the url property/home?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`$this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'New Post has been added');`
`redirect('somefunction', 'refresh')`
[set_flashdata](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html) after save successful will help you to destroy your submitted data and redirect will change your url.

Answer (score 0):

You need url helper to use

```
redirect('/home')
```

This is the correct way to redirect at CI. 
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

- the second param. is not 100% required

To load that helper you can use `$this->load->helper('url');`
or to write it inside your autoload.php at config folder (this way it will be loaded to all page).

For example here is one simple submition page at my site.

```
public function save_tips(){
    if($this->input->post('save_tips')){
        //Form validation and contact with model
        $res = $this->model->save_tips();
        if(count($res['errors'])==0){ //no errors means success
            redirect('/my_tips');
        } else{
        $errors = $res['errors'];
        }
    }

    $data = array();

    if(isset($errors)) {
        $data["errors"] = $errors;
    }

    $this->load->view('save_tips',$data);
}
```

Comment: I can't use redirect apparently because the header has been modified.

Comment: just put it before it ? why do you need to set headers before redirect line ?

Comment: it is saying that my model is sending output so what does "put it before it" mean in this case?

Comment: CI is MVC .. models shouldn't outputing anything.. 
You have controller for that job..

Comment: I know that Svetlio...I there is nothing outputting there and that's whats driving me crazy

Comment: Try to find where is the problem.. 
if you dont load the view, you dont echo anything and there are set headers, there must be whitespace somewhere which is causing this problem ;)

Comment: @sys_debug: if there are any warnings being generated by your code - that counts as output and will disallow a `redirect` call.

Comment: @Darrrrrren no any warnings are showing if I remove this redirect line code. :(

Comment: when you use redirect() do you load the url helper? $this->load->helper('url');

Answer (score 0):

`$this->load->view()` will only load the view and the url will not change .
When you use `redirect()` it will redirect to a different page and your url will change.

And for your solution You can select the data which you are going to insert in your model before inserting and if it exists then don't run the insert query simply redirect to a different page.

Answer (score 0):

i have faced same issue with codeigniter 3.1.7 , i have just simply validate the submit button value with name , example as below

in view side

```
<input type="submit" value="save" name = "submit">
```

in controller side

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){}
```